# function not recognizing macro input for sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to reformat a program's export. So far I've created a function that calls for a single string input, which is simply a number identifier (2210-01, for example). 
This input is causing issues once I go to navigate to the sheet by that name.

I've tried assigning the input datatype as something other than a string, but that's causing other issues. I know that my WB has those sheet names that are in the RunFormatRawExport(), I'm not sure why it's causing issues when I pull open the sheet though.

```
Sub RunFormatRawExport()
FormatRawExport ("2210-01")
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function FormatRawExport(ComCode As String)
    Sheets("ComCode").Activate
End Function
```

with this short snippet, the macro should just re navigate to sheet 2210-01. I'm not getting errors when I call for ComCode before this error.

Comment: no quotes: `Sheets(ComCode).Activate`

Comment: @ScottCraner that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you should first set focus to the workbook the sheet "CombCode" is in, i.e. Workbooks([name]).Activate

Comment: that seems odd that I'd need to do that if I only have one workbook open, ya? I've run the macro with a hardtyped string - that worked, so it still makes me think that it's something to do with the data type.

Comment: If you want manipulate and/or edit the sheet, it might be better to put the whole sheet in a Excelsheet object, something like dim sh as sheet; set sh=sheets("[name]"); etc